# How do I add a lint quickfix to "fix in whole project" for Java/Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lint

I am able to write a lint warning/error with a QuickFix to change some code in the IDE.

I also know that I can tag a Kotlin function with the @Deprecated tag, like so:

```
@Deprecated(
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR,
    message = "This is wrong",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("doRight(input)")
)
fun doWrong(input: String) {}
```

This generates a lint quickfix (LintFix) to replace the function. But it also generates a lint quickfix to replace the function in your entire project, like so:

[image: Whole Project Quickfix]

How do I write a custom LintFix that applies the quickfix not just to the current warning, but to all applicable warnings in the project?